# What does "class" mean in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I do not understand the meaning of `class` in Modelica context.

From the *Modelica Tutorial, version 1.4*  on https://modelica.org/publications.html:

> In Modelica, the basic structuring element is a class. There are seven restricted classes with specific names, such as model...". Anyone have a simpler explanation? I am very new to Modelica.

Comment: It is the same idea of class as in all object oriented programming. As a start, read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)

Comment: https://specification.modelica.org/master/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#specialized-classes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you open the Modelica library in a tool like Dymola or OpenModelica, everything you see in the package or library browser are classes.

As soon as you use one of these classes, e.g. with drag and drop in the diagram layer, you create a new component of this class type.
The instantiated component is not a copy of the class, but a reference to it. Therefore, if you update the class definition, you also update the behavior of all components that are instances of this class.

There are several kinds of classes available. The most general class is actually called `class`, but it’s not used very often.
It has no restrictions, so it can contain everything that is possible with Modelica: equations, algorithms, public and protected components, etc.

There are more specific class types, which restrict the usage. This helps to make correct use of a class. A `function` or a `record` for example cannot be simulated.

The most important restricted class types are:

- `package`: used to group other classes
- `model`: typically used for components with physical connectors and for examples which are simulated
- `block`: used for components with causal connectors (only inputs and outputs, so everything you have in `Modelica.Blocks`)
- `function`: used for function calls, comparable to other programming languages
- `record`: often used to contain data sets for other components (which allows to quickly change a complete data set)
- `connector`: used to define the interface variables which are needed to connect different components of a domain (e.g.  v and i in the electric domain)
- `type`: typically used to define physical quantities like mass, length or time with their unit (e.g. all units in the package `Modelica.Units`)

More information can be found in chapter 4.6 of the Modelica specification: [Specialized Classes](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#specialized-classes)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a collection of links to prove that there is an ongoing discussion on class within the Modelica Association:

1. [class still a valid Modelica class type to use?](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/1860)
2. [model no longer identical to class](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/1345)
3. [What is the usage recommendation for class?](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/issues/2128)
4. [Restricted class for parameter record with initial equation](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2311)

Comment: In some libraries, `class` is used to define an icon. Not sure if it is consistent with the Modelica Specification. Here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0U4G.jpg